# Django: multiple parameters in exclude are joined by OR insted of AND

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm

According to documentation, [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) joines multiple parameters by AND, but my query seems to use OR logic instead.

I have the following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # some fields
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

And I want to get all books except those, where is only one author and author's id is '12':

```
q_and = Book.objects.annotate(authors_number=Count('authors')).exclude(authors_number=1, authors__in=['12'])
```

But instead, I get result which is similar to query with OR logic:

```
q_or = Book.objects.annotate(authors_number=Count('authors')).exclude(authors_number=1).exclude(authors__in=['12'])
```

If I filter books with the only author and author's id='12', I get those I need to exclude:

```
need_to_exclude = Book.objects.annotate(authors_number=Count('authors')).filter(authors_number=1, authors__in=['12'])
```

I know how to make, what I want in two queries, but how to make the same with one query, using `exclude()`?

And what's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this; This is the OR operation.

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q(Q(authors_number=1)| Q(authors__in=['12']))
q_and = Book.objects.annotate(authors_number=Count('authors')).exclude(q).distinct()
```

Comment: I've tried this. The result is the same to my first two queries.

Comment: Maybe, the reason is in m2m filed?

Comment: Can you try with distinct()